# Search Sql option

Tags: php, sql

I have a search page that searches for registers in SQL database and I want to ad a checbox or a option box to search if the user has or not a contract.
Tried so many ways to connect with SQL function but i just couldn't do it :x

I eave here the other SQL's i have on the search :

```
SELECT registos.Cliente, registos.NS24, registos.N24H, registos.Contrato
FROM registos
WHERE registos.Cliente LIKE '%$_POST[Cliente_procurar]%'
  AND registos.NS24 LIKE '%$_POST[NS24_procurar]%' 
  AND registos.N24H LIKE '%$_POST[N24H_procurar]%'
```

I want it as check or not option or something but then i don't know how to Connect that to my

Comment: This is an sql query it will not give you any check box or any form input for that matter. Where is your html and php code?

Comment: The code i left is form dreamweaver recordset SQL. I have the form my problem is I dont know how to do sql Where to the check box. Name of checkbutton is "Check"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 //try :
 //connect:
 $link=mysql_connet('localhost','root','');
 //select database:
 mysql_select_db('databasename',$link);

 // and then use sql code in this function

 mysql_query("SELECT registos.Cliente, registos.NS24, registos.N24H, registos.Contrato
 FROM registos
 WHERE registos.Cliente LIKE '%$_POST[Cliente_procurar]%' AND registos.NS24 LIKE         '%$_POST[NS24_procurar]%' AND registos.N24H LIKE '%$_POST[N24H_procurar]%'" );
```

Comment: the mysql_* function are deprecated, use mysqli_* function instead.

And protect the db from Sql injection with escaping user input with mysqli_real_escape_string() (and int casting on integer value)